# Error while transferring pick list field between two objects via Visual flow with Global Picklist

Tags: visual-workflow, global-picklist

I have a visual flow and want to copy the values of a multi-select pick list field from one object to the other. Both objects have a multi-select pick list field based on the same global pick list.

[image: Visual Flow Element Screenshot]

However, I get the following error message when executing the flow:

`INSERT --- INSERT FAILED --- ERRORS: (INVALID_OR_NULL_FOR_RESTRICTED_PICKLIST) incorrect value for picklist with Strictly enforce picklist values: Agendamento,`

Since both refer to the same global pick list, its theoretically impossible that the value doesn't exist.

I also have the same routine set up for updating the quote based on the opportunity, and this works fine.

[image]

Since both are executed as flows by the administrator user, I do not see the difference here.

I found that article and understand that there has been a problem in the past that should have been solved:
https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008eF2AAI

Does anyone has an idea what might be the difference between both visual workflows that might cause the error appearing?